# Convert Arraylist<String> to an ArrayList<Integer> or Integer Array

Tags: java, type-conversion

I wanna make an apps that need to convert `ArrayList<String>[]` to `ArrayList<Integer>[]` , I also used this :

```
ArrayList<String>[] strArrayList;
int ArrayRes = (int) strArrayList[];
```

but this code get me an error , anybody can help me ?

Any suggestion would be appreciate

Comment: How do you wish to convert Array of an ArrayList of String to a single int? Question is vague.

Comment: Ali Ghanei, do you want to parse your string arraylist into integer arraylist? Simply are you asking that how to convert all string value of your arraylist into int value?

Comment: @HashimR A: Question is not vague by the way it was very clear , I just asked my problem.

Comment: Okay first thing, why don't you make simple ArrayList<String> ? And how do you want to convert whole ArrayList to a single int? Do you want to concatenate all Strings? you didn't mention anything so your question seems incomplete. No offense. :)

Comment: @HashimR: Well I used the source code that must be an integer.

Comment: @Ali Ghanei Check your selected answer is working also for that string which having alphabets?

Answer (score 17):

*Define a method which will convert all String value of arraylist
    into integer.*

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getIntegerArray(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(String stringValue : stringArray) {
            try {
                //Convert String to Integer, and store it into integer array list.
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
               //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + stringValue + " can not be an integer");
            } 
        }       
        return result;
    }
```

And simply call that method, as

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultList = getIntegerArray(strArrayList); //strArrayList is a collection of Strings as you defined.
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Use `result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue.trim());` to avoid whitespaces from causing needless exception errors.

Answer (score 5):

How about this one

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class sample7 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            ArrayList<String> strArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            strArrayList.add("1");
            strArrayList.add("11");
            strArrayList.add("111");
            strArrayList.add("12343");
            strArrayList.add("18475");
            List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(strArrayList.size()) ;
            for (String myInt : strArrayList) 
            { 
              newList.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt)); 
            }
            System.out.println(newList);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast an array of ArrayList objects to an int.  Of course you get an error.

First of all, you want a plain old `ArrayList`, not an array of `ArrayList`s.

Second, you use `Integer.parseInt()` to turn `String` objects into `int`s.  `int` is a primitive type, not a class type, and certainly not a superclass of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast list of strings to ints like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < strArrayList.size(); i++) {
   numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(strArrayList.get(i)));   
}
```

Comment: strArrayList[i] would give you an `ArrayList` type, which is not a valid argument for `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: ArrayList<int> ???? are you sure ?? I think it will be ArrayList<Integer> rather ArrayList<int>

Answer (score -8):

Iterator on the list and parse them into Integers:

(WARN: not tested)

```
ArrayList<String> strArrayList;
int[] ArrayRes = new int[strArrayList.size()];

int i = 0;
for (String s : strArrayList)
{
    ArrayRes[i++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

You can then convert them to a single int value based on how you wish to concatenate them.

Comment: Its asking for a conversion of ArrayList to int  not int[]