# Elegant way to convert a String[] to an int[] (or an ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>)

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I am building an Android application where I receive a message that are numbers, separated by a comma delimiter. A sample input would be:

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,31,12,13,16
```

And I receive this and assign it as a String, then make a String[] by using the split method as such:

```
String input = "1,2,3,4,1,2,31,12,13,16";
String[] arrayInput = input.split(",");
```

And now I have an array version of my input. The next thing I want to do is to convert this to an `int[]` for the main purpose of elegant coding.

Now, I just can't go with:

```
int[] aGroup = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayInput, 0, 3);
```

because I'll get a type mismatch. Trying to be clever, I tried:

```
int[] aGroup = Integer.valueOf(Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayInput, 0 ,3));
```

But `Integer.valueOf()` would expect a single string input and not several array elements.

I know I can go with a fancy for-each loop as such:

```
List<Integer> arrayInputInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String entry : arrayInput){
    arrayInputInt.add(Integer.valueOf(entry));
}
```

or something to that effect. While this for-each loop looks clean and elegant, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant, pleasing to the eye, one liner String[] to int[] converter.

### Edit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708698/convert-arrayliststring-to-an-arraylistinteger-or-integer-array) was linked as my problem was a possible duplicate of this question. The answers in the question uses loops to go through each element in the String ArrayList, try to parse them, and then convert it to Integer and place it in the Integer ArrayList. The solution I'm looking for is a one line-no loop used type of a String[] to int[] conversion.

Comment: You could use RxJava `map`

Comment: I don't think so as I haven't updated my Java yet.

Comment: I skipped over you're using Android, so you'll need to download the RxJava library to use Streams

Comment: I don't see anything android related here

Comment: @AdamSkywalker first sentence. I edited the title, but it should be known that Java 8 can't (directly)  be used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Arraylist<String> to an ArrayList<Integer> or Integer Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708698/convert-arrayliststring-to-an-arraylistinteger-or-integer-array)

Comment: `I edited the title,` If you added the 'Android' then please remove it. The problem has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: @greenapps It might. As 'cricket_007' pointed out in my answer, "It's an Android app. Doesn't natively support lambda".

Comment: @greenapps You are welcome to view the full edit history. The title had Android, but I removed thinking a non Java 8 solution would be posted, then they were all Java 8, so I put it back

Answer (score 1):

Before lambda, i solve that issue by creating converter interface, and convertList utility method as below

```
 interface Converter<S,T>{ 
        T convert(S source); 
 }



  class ListConverter{ 
       static public <S,T> List<T> convertList(List<S> source,Converter<S,T> converter){ 
         List<T> target= new ArrayList<>();
         for (S s : source){ 
            target.add(converter(s)); 
         }
         return target; 
       }
   }
```

then if you want to use it, you can do

```
List<Integer> ints = ListConverter.convertList(Arrays.asList(input.split(","),new Converter<String,Integer>(){
public Integer convert(String source){
return Integer.parseInt(source);

}
})
```

Obviously you don't need instantiate converter each time when you need it, you could create singletons for common converters

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numberStrs = line.split(",");
int[] numbers = new int[numberStrs.length];

for(int i = 0;i < numberStrs.length;i++) {
    /*
     * Note that this is assuming valid input
     * If you want to check then add a try/catch 
     * and another index for the numbers if to continue adding the others
     */
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Nice attempt to answer, but in question better way is already written then what you have answered. you need to give more better option then used in code. May be one liner...

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking to use a lambda expression like so? (This will require importing `RxJava`)

```
// List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
// s.add("1");
// s.add("2");               // ["1","2"]
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
s.forEach((val) -> list.add(Integer.valueOf(val)));   // or parseInt
// System.out.println(list); // [1,2]
```

Comment: It's an Android app. Doesn't natively support lambda

Comment: I see. @cricket_007 Won't the `RxJava` libraries help?

Comment: They will, but I think retrolambda also needs included if you want to use lambdas

Comment: @cricket_007 That might just be a lot of importing libraries for something like this, no? Or do you think it's worth it?

Comment: For something this simple, no, but I've seen projects with tens of libraries included, so as long as they provide some functionality, it's worth it. That's the price of elegance in code.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yea. That's somewhat aligns with what I was thinking.

Comment: @cricket_007 there is retrolambda for that. also lambdas are coming to android

Comment: more importantly, Android does not have `forEach` on iterables

Comment: @njzk2 I mentioned retrolambda in that second comment

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]";
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(",")).map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Android doesn't have Java 8 features

Comment: Android doesn't seem to have a Arrays.stream() method.

Comment: you have to make ur java to java 8 ,it will run on android also.

Comment: @Amit As I was trying to say, Android can't compile and run Java 8.

Comment: not only it does not yet have java 8 features (which you can add), Android does not have java 8 functions, like `Arrays.stream`

Answer (score 0):

Using [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) and [a little library for functional things](https://github.com/smaspe/FunctionalIterables/):

```
List<Integer> res = FuncIter
    .iter(input.split(","))
    .map(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect();
```

Nota: retrolambda gives you function references and lambdas from java 8. The FuncIter library is a very simple collection of higher-order functions like `map`.